# Can someone help find methods to study the asymptotic behavior of these integrals as $\rho \to \infty$?

Tags: integration, asymptotics

I want to know methods to study the asymptotic behavior as $\rho \to \infty$ of the following integrals where $\rho>0$ and $q \geq 0$:
$$ \int_{-1}^{1} e^{-\rho t} (1-t^2)^{q-1/2}dt$$
$$ \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-\rho t}(t^2-1)^{q-1/2}dt$$

I tried use Watson's Lemma, but I think this lemma only works for integrals $\int_{0}^{t}$ which is not the case above, I tried use Laplace's method too, but the above case does not enter in the hypothesis of the method, and now I don't know how to proceed, I need help, thank you.

Comment: The  second case should be easier by factoring out $e^{-\rho t/2} \leq e^{-\rho/2} \to 0.$ The same argument works in the first integral over the two intervals defined by $1/2 \leq |t| \leq 1$ and using that $(1-t^2) \leq c < 1$ on $|t| \leq 1/2,$ so $e^{-\rho t} (1-t^2)^{q-1/2} \leq c^{q-1/2} \to 0$ for $|t| \leq 1/2.$

Comment: Sorry, I confused $\rho$ and $q.$ I am sure that the first integrals tend to zero as $\rho \to \infty,$ the second family should also go to zero but it won't be as easy to see.

Comment: The second integral is extremely similar to the first : it involves $K_q(\rho )$ instead of $I_q(\rho )$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watson's Lemma will still apply, since the dominant contribution is from the left hand end of the interval.  You can shift the integral to start at zero:

\begin{align*}
I &= \int_{-1}^1 e^{-\rho t}(1-t^2)^{q-1/2} dt \\
&= e^\rho\int_{-1}^1 e^{-\rho(t+1)}(1-t^2)^{q-1/2} dt \\
&= e^\rho \int_{0}^2 e^{-\rho u}u^{q-1/2}(2-u)^{q-1/2} du
\end{align*}
Applying Watson's Lemma to this integral (just the leading order term; for the full expansion, you would have to expand $(2-u)^{q-1/2}$):
\begin{align*}
I &\sim e^\rho \int_0^\infty 2^{q-1/2} u^{q-1/2}e^{-\rho u} du \\
&= 2^{q-1/2}\rho^{-q-1/2}e^\rho\int_0^\infty v^{q-1/2}e^{-v} dv \\
&= 2^{q-1/2}\Gamma(q+1/2)\rho^{-q-1/2}e^\rho.
\end{align*}
Similar argument for the second integral.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the help, where can I find the version of the Watson's Lemma that you applied?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma

Comment: But why your asymptotic approximation is not a series? I don't understood too what do you mean by the expression "leading order term", could you ( if possible) detail a little more the application of Watson's Lemma? Thank you very much for the response

Comment: In the language of that link, $\lambda = q-1/2$, and $g(u) = (2-u)^{q-1/2}$.  I have found the first term in the Taylor series expansion of $g$, $g(0) = 2^{q-1/2}$, and used it to find the first term in the asymptotic series expansion for the integral.  If you find all the terms in the Taylor series expansion of $g$, that will generate all the terms in the asymptotic series.

Answer (score 1):

**Here are some coarse ideas.**

Note that $t^2-1>0$ on $t > 1$ and $1-t^2>0$ on $|t|<1.$ Escribe $e^{-\rho t} = e^{-\rho t/2} e^{-\rho t/2} \leq e^{-\rho/2} e^{-\rho t/2}$ for $t > 1.$ Then,
$$
\int\limits_1^\infty dt\ e^{-\rho t} (t^2-1)^{q-1/2} \leq e^{-\rho/2} I_\rho,
$$
where $I_\rho = \int\limits_1^\infty dt\ e^{-\rho t/2} (t^2 - 1)^{q-1/2}$ is finite for $\rho  > 0$ and it is decreasing on $\rho,$ so as $\rho \to \infty$ you can eventually bound $I_{2\rho} \leq e^{-\rho/2} I_1.$ For the other integral, I realised it diverges exponentially fast,
$$
\int\limits_{-1}^1 dt\ e^{-\rho t} (1 - t^2)^{q - 1/2} \geq \int_{-1}^{-1/2} dt\ e^{-\rho t} (1-t^2)^{q-1/2} \geq e^{\rho/2} J_q,
$$
where $J_q$ is a convergent integral depending on $q$ but not $\rho.$

Comment: thank you so much, very helpful, your method avoids the use of the Watson's Lemma which is nice!

Comment: If you like, upvote.

Comment: the +1 vote was mine, I'm still deciding which answer to aceppt.

Answer (score 1):

If you let $t=\cos(x)$ and if $q$ is a positive integer you find something which is quite close to the integral formulae of the modified Bessel functions of the first kind (have a look [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32)). Using $10.32.2$ of the $DLMF$ linked page, for th first integral
$$I=\int_{-1}^{+1} e^{-\rho  t}\,\left(1-t^2\right)^{q-\frac{1}{2}}\,dt=\sqrt{\pi }\,\, 2^q\,  \Gamma \left(q+\frac{1}{2}\right)\,\rho ^{-q}\, I_q(\rho )$$
$$\rho ^{-q}\, I_q(\rho )=\frac{e^{\rho } \rho ^{- \left(q+\frac{1}{2}\right)}}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\Bigg[1+\frac{1-4 q^2}{8 \rho }+\frac{16 q^4-40 q^2+9}{128 \rho
   ^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{\rho^3 }\right) \Bigg]$$ So
$$I=2^{q-\frac{1}{2}}  \Gamma \left(q+\frac{1}{2}\right) e^{\rho }\rho ^{-
   \left(q+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{\rho}\right)\right)$$ as already given by @messenger.

Using this last expression for $q=\pi$ and $\rho=100$ gives $3.40636\times 10^{27 }$ while the exact value is $3.24562\times 10^{27 }$. Using the expansion to $O\left(\frac{1}{\rho^3 }\right)$ gives $3.24564\times 10^{27 }$ .

Comment: Instead of adding $O(1/\rho)$ you should multiply by $1+O(1/\rho)$.